# Want to construct a polynomial with specific properties.

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I'm looking to construct a polynomial $p$ such that the following hold:

1. $p$ has only one zero in the unit disc.
2. $p(1)=1$
3. $|p(z)|<1$ for all $|z|\leq 1, z\neq 1$

Context: I was trying to prove that the hypothesis for [Rouche's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) are necessary.

Comment: can you please explain the link between Rouche's Theorem and this problem?

Comment: Rouche's theorem says that if $|f(z)|<|g(z)|$ on the curve, then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros inside the curve. I wanted to know if the theorem holds even if $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ just for a single point. If I get such a polynomial, then the answer is no.

Comment: $z^2+z-1$ is almost a solution; it has magnitude $1$ at only $\pm 1$ and has only one root in the unit circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These properties hold for $p(z) = \frac{1}{5}(z^2 + 3z + 1)$:

It is easy enough to check that it has only one root in the unit circle.  To check that the absolute value condition is met, we can use the maximum principle, and compute $|p(e^{it})|^2 = \frac{1}{25}(2\cos t + 3)^2$ to find that $|p(z)|$ achieves its maximum on the unit disc for $z=1$.

Comment: @Kelenner Good point; the maximum is on the other side.  I've modified the example, and I believe it to be correct now.

Comment: Ok, I think it works now (+1).